# I'm trying to make fingers, already tried re-rigging it, but it is bending weird

Tags: rigging

I'm trying to make fingers, already tried re-rigging it, but it is bending weird

[image]

Comment: Hello make sure that the normals are correctly oriented and maybe reparent or assign the vertices manually, or share your file

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)